# When I use javascript:alert(document.lastModified) alert appears, but no information enclosed

Tags: php, google-chrome, firefox6

When I use the following, javascript:alert(document.lastModified), in Chrome to check whether my site was updated, the alert dialog box appears, but there is no content within the box. My page is powered by PHP, therefore it should display the time and date of page request should it not?

Answer (score 0):

PHP-generated pages don't have last-modified dates. They're dynamically generated, so by definition their last-modified data is "now", regardless of how much dynamic data is actually served, or if the output hasn't changed since the last time. You'd have to set a last-modified header yourself, using `header()`.

Comment: What about ASP pages then? They are also server-generated aren't they? Yet they display last-modified information.

Comment: Completely different environment/language.

Comment: but it is server generated though, the time displayed is the current time and date. Oh well! Thanks for your help.

Comment: @happy: ASP.NET does a lot more on your behalf than PHP does. afaik, unless you tell it otherwise using `header()`, PHP generates the `HTTP/1.1 200 OK\n` header and `Content-Type: text/html\n\n` header and that's it... although the web server may add a few additional headers of its own.